# Django count foreign key through relation

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am building a simple **forum** application and I need some help with **counting foreign** key objects via through relation.

Let's say my models look like this:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(to=Forum, related_name='threads')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(to=Thread,related_name='posts')
```

Now we create `forum` object.

```
forum = Forum.objects.get(slug=forum)
```

We can count the number of threads inside forum like this: `forum.threads.count()`

**My question is, how can i count all the posts in a forum?**

I've tried something like `all_posts = forum.thredas.posts.count()` but as expected it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally in Django it is a good principle that when you want to do something with a model, you should start your query from that model. So, since you need to count posts, you should start with the Post model.

From there you can use the double-underscore syntax to filter to the particular Forum you want.

```
forum_posts = Post.objects.filter(thread__forum=my_forum)
forum_post_count = forum_posts.count()
```